# Unable to generate Access token for flipkart API

Tags: oauth-2.0, httpurlconnection, flipkart-api

I am trying to get New access token for Oauth 2.0 with client credential. I am always getting Forbidden or unauthorized error. While I can directly login to url https://api.flipkart.net/oauth-service/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=Seller_Api and generate the token but going with below code I am not able to generate token

```
public static String getAccessToken(OAuth2Details oauthDetails) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection con;
        String accessToken = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://api.flipkart.net/oauth-service/oauth/token\?grant_type\=client_credentials\&scope=Seller_Api");
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            String clientId = oauthDetails.getClientId();
            String clientSecret = oauthDetails.getClientSecret();
            String scope = oauthDetails.getScope();


                System.out
                        .println("Authorization server expects Basic authentication");

                con.setRequestProperty(
                        OAuthConstants.AUTHORIZATION,
                        getBasicAuthorizationHeader(oauthDetails.getClientId(),
                                oauthDetails.getClientSecret()));

                System.out.println("Retry with client credentials");

                int code = con.getResponseCode();
                System.out.print(con.getResponseMessage());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        con.getErrorStream()));

                if (code == 401 || code == 403) {

                    String s;
                    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.print(br.readLine());
                    }
                    con.disconnect();
                    System.out
                            .println("Could not authenticate using client credentials.");
                    throw new RuntimeException(
                            "Could not retrieve access token for client: "
                                    + oauthDetails.getClientId());

                }

            }

            Map<String, String> map = handleResponse(con);
            accessToken = map.get(OAuthConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return accessToken;
    }

    public static String getBasicAuthorizationHeader(String username,
            String password) {
        System.out.println("uu" + OAuthConstants.BASIC + " "
                + encodeCredentials(username, password));
        return OAuthConstants.BASIC + " "
                + encodeCredentials(username, password);
    }

    public static String encodeCredentials(String username, String password) {
        String cred = username + ":" + password;

        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(cred.getBytes()));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "\" from your url

```
url = new URL("https://api.flipkart.net/oauth-service/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=Seller_Api");
```

Also make the app-id and and secretlike this

```
<app-id>:<app_secret>

example kdfjkfjdsakfjd93842908039489:kdjsfkajidsjf8939034820

oauthDetails.getClientId()+":"+oauthDetails.getClientSecret()
```